# Controlling DC voltage with Arduino

Tags: arduino, voltage-regulator

My projects consists of:

- Arduino Nano
- 1m 60Leds 12V LedStrip (white)
- 1m 60Leds 5V controllable LedStrip (RGB)
- 5V power supply
- step up converter (from 5V to 12V)
- potentiometer
- some trigger buttons
- some sensors

I'm making a "lamp" of sorts, that would be controlled through Arduino Nano.

I'm powering it with 5V power supply (phone charger); I have step up converter setup for 12V; potentiometer output 0V-5V to Arduino analog input.

---

One of the functions would be "dimmable LEDs", controlled by Arduino, according to audio and light sensors.

This is no problem for the RGB strip, as they have additional data pin and I can control them that way, but when it comes to 12V white LEDs...

Using lab bench power supply I found out, that white LED strip turns on at 8V and with voltage rising to 12V it gets brighter.

The natural thought was "put a potentiometer there", but I'm already using one potentiometer, as analog input for Arduino (so 5V).

---

I don't want to use another potentiometer, as it would be against DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

---

I've seen "solutions", as to use PWM together with MOSFET to run the 12V LEDs, but I don't want to introduce "flickering" (even though it might be insusceptible to humans, it may affect my kids falling asleep [they seem to not be able to fall asleep with LEDs connected to mains, while they can with old incandescent bulbs]).

I've also taken a look at "digital potentiometers" (like FM62429 or X9C104), but they all seem to be made for audio signals or lower voltage usages, not 12V.

---

Soo, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to make "nice" 8-12V DC using MOSFET and PWM?
2. Can I make some circuit that would use digital potentiometers and not overheat them?
3. Is there a better way to make that project work?

Comment: What I meant about the PWM and MOSFETs - I don't really want pulse modulated brightness. What I want to do, is something like "Arduino controlled step down converter".

Comment: Without a built-in feature in your LED item, you can control brightness by: (1) controlling the current with a sufficiently high compliance voltage capability; (2) by controlling the voltage with a sufficiently high compliance current capability; (3) setting a fixed voltage and using PWM; or (4) setting a fixed current and using PWM. That's not all the options. There are still more complex ones. But those are the easier ones. Which of them you use depends on what you have at hand. Your 5 V LED chain seems to have a "feature." That's good. The white LED appears to need one of the above ideas.

Comment: If you pulse well past the flicker fusion frequency (say, pulse frequencies well above 150 Hz) then it shouldn't be a problem. You could just "go crazy" and pick 1 kHz or even 10 kHz, if you want. Fast enough and it is very unlikely to be an issue. The eye "integrates" over short periods for which these very fast frequencies are "fast." But if you must do it linearly without flicker at all, then set up 12 V and use a current controller. Even then, you'll want geometric progression for brightness control as humans perceive the log of current (needed to survive on planet Earth.)

Comment: Could you point me to current controller schematics or some link, where to buy one?

Comment: Are you saying your kids are not humans?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I think the OP's worried about brain development and his own lack of knowledge (ignorance, which we all suffer from) about what matters and what does not matter as a child's brain grows and develops. We engineers make a whole lot of assumptions about what's reasonable without even knowing if it is. For example, plants actually need a tiny "reset" cycle time on the order of a small number of microseconds. That would normally be a surprise to us, as the sun is assumed to be "on" and not to flicker. So why? Because that's quantum mechanics and plants must obey it. So it's caution?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Another example of ignorance is the CRMP2 molecule in the human brain. 10 years ago, scientists assumed that once phosphorylated as part of an ATP process step, that phosphorylated CRMP2 was "inactive" (inert) and at a dead end. So it could be ignored. Turns out, phosphorylated CRMP2 is far from it. It's actually critical. It enhances the entry of calcium following membrane depolarization, in presynaptic N-type calcium channels in the hippocampal and sensory neurons; controls exoskeleton development in dendritic structures and is crucial in neurite-axon dynamics. to name a few.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Who knows what fast-flashing lights do to a 1yr old brain, for example? Do you? We are still in the bone knifes and bear skins epoch, just beginning to crawl out of horrible ignorance. We've only just recently uncovered the fact that there is cluster of neuron structures in the stomach area that approximates the number found in pig brains. Now, there's whole new studies on the newly uncovered "gut-brain axis!" I can understand parents' concerns about flickering lights. I don't agree with those concerns. But I can well understand them.

Comment: @jonk I was really just questioning his statement that the PWM would be "insusceptible [sic] to humans, it may affect kids" which suggested that his kids were not humans. Based on what I have seen lately, I am totally convinced that rapidly flashing lights, particularly those in the displays of smart devices, are making our children stupid. But I am really just jesting, so you don't need to write three long comments telling me about the biology of young brains.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I just like reminding myself (and using you as a foil to do so) about how much we assume and how much we actually don't know much about. Not only in electronics but in what we do to make processed food supplies that "keep" long enough, etc. You were just convenient. Sorry about that. Nothing personal.

Comment: No, sorry, you misunderstood me @jonk
What I meant was - my younger son has trouble falling asleep.

We often just turned off all electronics in his room and then it improved.

I found out that with old incandescent light bulbs he can sleep with light on, while with LED powered with mains he cant.

I am well aware, that flashing lights doesn't really affect healthy people.

Comment: @Gaben Interesting. Thanks for that. (Probably should have added it in the question, though I have had fun anyway.) So, you don't want any flickering. Then you'll probably want current control. It's usually sufficient to have two orders of magnitude range, but to be honest humans have adapted over millions of years to see with a range of light that exceeds 8 orders of magnitude of illumination. This includes pupils, fast neural adaptation, photochemical adaptation, different cell types in the eye, and others. So two orders may not be enough or too much. You'll need to decide that part.

Comment: @Gaben, there is a possibility that your son cannot fall asleep with an LED lamp may be because of sound being produced by the lamp, sound that is outside of an adult's audio range

Comment: @jonk, your comment about plants needing a "reset" is absolutely intriguing ... where have you seen info about that? ... madame google does not want to give up any secrets ... lol

Comment: @jsotola I have dozens of papers from NASA on the topic, which is where I sourced that little tidbit. I'm sure the ESA has equivalent material. As you can well imagine, in a domain where it's nearly impossible to get rid of unwanted heat (all you have is radiation) and where every erg matters, they'd research what it takes to maximize plant production. And they have been investigating this for years. The papers I saw went to great pains to nail down exact wavelengths, when those wavelengths are needed, how long they are needed, and how entire plant cycles reset (catalytic.)

Comment: @jonk I see a lot of recursive discussions here, and I am not sure why the OP is passing on the obvious choice most of us would make, and that would be MOSFET PWM at 12 to 15 volts. One can use RC to convert to variable DC, but much power is wasted. Blue light will keep you awake at night, so it should be avoided. This post is getting long in the tooth.

Comment: @Sparky256 The OP doesn't want flicker, apparently, because of prior experience with unknown products with unknown flicker. So give a linear solution?

Comment: After a quick 2hour night sleep I came into conclusion, that my "non-flickering" solution won't work, simply because I'm using DC to DC step up converter (XL6019), which in itself adds "flicker" at 220KHz, so I guess I'll have to live with that, as I won't include two battery modules in it. If anyone wants to make a "full answer" I'll gladly "accept it".

Comment: @jonk Rational solution (my opinion) is to use MOSFET's and PWM so MPU control is easy, then use RC filter so LED's get only DC current. RC filter per LED string would keep RC heat down. LC filter more efficient but wrong value of L would create harmonics. Multiple PWM LED's not synchronous to each other can induce flicker.

Comment: @Sparky256 Well, I think you've got the go-ahead from Gaben. He's accepting PWM, now. But since he already has 220 kHz, make it some frequency that is relatively prime to 220 kHz and where there is no least common denominator frequency below, say 200 Hz. We wouldn't want any low frequency flicker to appear as a beat frequency. Probably need to make it tunable, just in case, in order to exclude accidental LCD frequencies that are too low. Extra credit for a PID approach that automatically detects lower order beat frequencies and moves around to exclude them, dynamically.

Comment: @Gaben How many LED channels are you running? They must be synchronous or they will appear to flicker. It is the deference in pulses that creates a low frequency "beat" which is seen as flicker. If RC used R will get hot at high brightness.

Comment: I'm using LED strip: SMD2835, 60 led/m connected directly to power supply (I guess step up converter), with 2 pins. They run parallel. While testing, whole 5m strip didn't use more than 0.7A at 12V, and here I plan to use ~1m, so 2W or so power.

Comment: @Gaben What active devices (BJTs or MOSFETs) do you have on-hand? I'm particularly interested in the higher-powered variety, right now (because of the near 1 amp requirement.)

Comment: @jonk just checked - just a few IRF840 but I can buy something if it won't be enough

Comment: @Gaben That thing is about \$1\:\Omega\$ when you provide about \$10\:\text{V}\$ to the gate. So it will drop about \$1\:\text{V}\$ and consume less than \$1\:\text{W}\$. You can expect, without a heat sink, that it will be about \$50^\circ\text{C}\$ above ambient. Which is hot. But probably workable. You could double them up to help that out, though. Just the same, you'll want a LOT of gate voltage. More than the MCU can deliver. Lucky for you, you have 12 V available! Any BJTs floating about?

Comment: I have KD3055 NPN 60V/15A/115W lying around, but don't you think it would be an overkill?

Comment: @Gaben Yes. I was hoping you might have some small signal devices.

Comment: Add a MOSFET for PWM. Then put an inductor in series with the LEDs, and then a diode in *reverse* parallel with the LEDs+inductor. Now you have a buck converter.  Instead of being all the way on and then all the way off, the LEDs will get brighter while the MOSFET is on and get dimmer while it is off - the inductor will average out the flickering. (In theory. I haven't actually tried this circuit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try concluding on the comments a bit, and add personal commentary.

- The standard way is really PWM'ing LEDs. When using a high PWM frequency, humans can't detect that it's PWM. There's relatively solid statistics and theory behind that's the case.
- If you don't want PWM, the appropriate way to dim an LED is to vary the current (illumination strength is pretty much proportional to current, which itself is pretty much exponential with voltage).
- You can build a controlled current source using your MCU, and MOSFETs

Personal notes:

- if your child can't sleep with a given light, but with another:

  - account for external control factors (sound emissions, light position, time of day, the fact that an incandescent bulb makes more infrared heat radiation than visible light and your child might just like the warming effect)
  - it's well-known that "bluer" lights tend to keep people awake more than warmish white tints. (and the latter is exactly what the incandescent light provides) You can buy "warm" white LEDs. What you're looking for is "color temperature", and that should be relatively low (2700 K - 2900 K).
- You could use a step-down converter LED driver IC. That has the advantage of not being a linear solution and hence not getting as hot.

  - Many come with a current limit pin, which needs to be connected to a low-side shunt resistor. When the current is high, the voltage over that resistor is high. You can use an opamp voltage adder to add a voltage to that voltage so that you can adjust the current externally.
  - You could use the PWM followed by a simple RC low-pass filter to generate a voltage to add to that, giving you software. That's a voltage DAC!
- Of course, you could also build a linear regulator:

  - PWM -> low pass for a voltage DAC
  - 12V ->  high-side MOSFET configuration (that's nontrivial) driven by opamp -> LEDs -> Ground as the power chain
  - low side of MOSFET -> Voltage divider to a voltage range your DAC could also produce (e.g. 12 V maps to 3V)
  - connect divided voltage to non-inverting input of opamp from above. The opamp is now in a negative-feedback configuration, which means it will try to output exactly as much as necessary to make the voltage at its two inputs equal.
  - connect DAC to non-inverting input. This now allows your MCU to control the voltage at the voltage divider's output, and hence the voltage that the LEDs see.
  - pull down non-inverting input via 1 MΩ to ground. That way, when your MCU is off/malfunctions, the lights turn off.